# asp net core edit with list of base types

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, inheritance, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to create an edit view that contains an object with a list of base objects.

My example is a zoo which contains a list of Animal objects (Lion, Monkey etc)

I can populate the view with data but when I save, the post method recieves a list of Animal ojects not a list containing Lions and Monkeys.

Below is my controller

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using WebApplication2.Models;

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class ZooController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Zoo
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // GET: Zoo/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            return View(new Zoo()
            {
                Animals = new List<Animal>() {
                    new Lion() { 
                    Name="Simba",
                    Legs=4,
                    RoarDecibels=100},
                    new Monkey() {
                    Name="Rafiki",
                    Legs=4,
                    MaxClimbHeight=50}
                }
            });
        }

        // POST: Zoo/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, Zoo zoo)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add update logic here

                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below ismy Zoo edit View "Views/Zoo/Edit.cshtml"

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.Zoo
@using WebApplication2.Models

<h1>Edit</h1>

<h4>Zoo</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Animals.Count(); i++)
            {
                switch (Model.Animals[i])
                {
                    case Lion l:
                        <partial name="Lion" for=@Model.Animals[i] />
                        break;
                    case Monkey m:
                        <partial name="Monkey" for=@Model.Animals[i] />
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Below is my Lion edit view "Views/Zoo/Lion.cshtml"

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.Lion

<h4>Lion</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="RoarDecibels" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="RoarDecibels" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="RoarDecibels" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Legs" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Legs" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Legs" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Below are my models

```
namespace WebApplication2.Models
{
    public class Zoo
    {
        public List<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
    }
    public class Animal
    {
        public int Legs { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class Lion : Animal
    {
        public int RoarDecibels { get; set; }
    }
    public class Monkey : Animal
    {
        public int MaxClimbHeight { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm pretty new to complex types in aspnetcore so not quite sure what i'm doing wrong or if there's a better way to do this. I've found a couple of questions on here and goodle but they all seem to be from 5-10 years ago in old asp and I can't figure out how to apply in aspnetcore.

Comment: Any update? Does my reply help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, asp.net core default model binding doesn't support Polymorphic model binding.

If you want to set it support Polymorphic model binding, you should use custom model bindings to check if the Animals type.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

First of all, you should modify the Animals model to add a new property named kind.

```
public class Animal
{
    public int Legs { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Kind { get; set; }
}
```

Then you should add custom model binding as below:

You should modify the `subclasses` and `modelTypeValue condition` according to Animals sub class names.

```
public class AnimalModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context.Metadata.ModelType != typeof(Animal))
        {
            return null;
        }

        var subclasses = new[] { typeof(Lion), typeof(Monkey), };

        var binders = new Dictionary<Type, (ModelMetadata, IModelBinder)>();
        foreach (var type in subclasses)
        {
            var modelMetadata = context.MetadataProvider.GetMetadataForType(type);
            binders[type] = (modelMetadata, context.CreateBinder(modelMetadata));
        }

        return new AnimalModelBinder(binders);
    }

    public class AnimalModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        private Dictionary<Type, (ModelMetadata, IModelBinder)> binders;

        public AnimalModelBinder(Dictionary<Type, (ModelMetadata, IModelBinder)> binders)
        {
            this.binders = binders;
        }

        public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var modelKindName = ModelNames.CreatePropertyModelName(bindingContext.ModelName, nameof(Animal.Kind));
            var modelTypeValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelKindName).FirstValue;

            IModelBinder modelBinder;
            ModelMetadata modelMetadata;
            if (modelTypeValue == "Lion")
            {
                (modelMetadata, modelBinder) = binders[typeof(Lion)];
            }
            else if (modelTypeValue == "Monkey")
            {
                (modelMetadata, modelBinder) = binders[typeof(Monkey)];
            }
            else
            {
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed();
                return;
            }

            var newBindingContext = DefaultModelBindingContext.CreateBindingContext(
                bindingContext.ActionContext,
                bindingContext.ValueProvider,
                modelMetadata,
                bindingInfo: null,
                bindingContext.ModelName);

            await modelBinder.BindModelAsync(newBindingContext);
            bindingContext.Result = newBindingContext.Result;

            if (newBindingContext.Result.IsModelSet)
            {
                // Setting the ValidationState ensures properties on derived types are correctly 
                bindingContext.ValidationState[newBindingContext.Result] = new ValidationStateEntry
                {
                    Metadata = modelMetadata,
                };
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Edit Controller:

```
    // POST: Zoo/Edit/5
    [HttpPost]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, Zoo zoo)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add update logic here

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks this solved my issue.
only extra I had to add was the add the binder provider in the startup

services.AddControllersWithViews(options=>
            {
                options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new AnimalModelBinderProvider());
            });